# c# SqlKata Insert values are showing as empty when logging compiled query

Tags: c#, sql, dynamic, sqlkata

I have the following code, which takes dynamic objects like this: (of underlying type JObject, fields can be different but it'll always be a JObject, not an array or anything else)

```
{
    "TRS_KEY": 1720,
    "TRS_PTR": 11,
    "TicTtl": false,
    "VoidTic": false,
    "SaveTrs": false,
    "RclTrs": false,
    "DrvOff": false,
    "QuickStore": false,
    "InfGTtl": true,
    "TndrXchng": false,
    "CpnTic": false,
    "TndrTic": false,
    "IHPay": false,
    "IHPurch": false,
    "SendEmail": false,
    "TicetID": 577,
    "TaxVal": 0,
    "Items": 0,
    "Amount": 0,
    "DiscAmt": 0,
    "AmountNT": 0,
    "DiscNT": 0,
    "GTtlAmt": 9088.9,
    "RetnID": 0,
    "FSPmt": 0,
    "AmtEleCpn": 0,
    "ZCnt": 0,
    "TailFlags": 8,
    "MmbrFirst": false
}
```

And loops through each one, converting the field names into columns and the values into, well, values for creating a SQL INSERT. The code:

```
foreach (dynamic d in r.Data)
{
    //context.Logger.LogLine($"{d.GetType()}");
    try
    {
        context.Logger.LogLine($"{r.TableRef} {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d)}");

        JObject o = d;
        var result = o.Descendants()
                      .OfType<JProperty>()
                      .Select(p => new KeyValuePair<string, object>(p.Path,
                                        p.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array || p.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object
                                        ? null : p.Value));

        IEnumerable<string> columns = result.Select(p => p.Key);
        IEnumerable<object> values = result.Select(p => p.Value);

        // Add custom columns
        IEnumerable<string> colAdded = columns.Add("STORE_ID").Add("last_modified");

        IEnumerable<object> valAdded = values.Add(state.StoreId).Add(DateTime.Now);

        foreach (var v in valAdded)
        {
            context.Logger.LogLine($"{JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v)}");
        }

        var queryResult = db.Query(r.TableRef).AsInsert(colAdded, valAdded);
        queryResult.Get();

        context.Logger.LogLine($"COLUMNS {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(columns,Formatting.Indented)}");
        context.Logger.LogLine($"VALUES {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values, Formatting.Indented)}");

        //var columns = result.Select(pairs => result.Select(pair => pair.Key).ToArray().ToString());
        //context.Logger.LogLine($"COLUMNS {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(columns)}");
        //var values = result.Select(pairs => result.Select(pair => pair.Value).ToArray());
        //context.Logger.LogLine($"VALUES TO GO INTO INSERTS {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values)}");
        //var queryResult = db.Query("S2C").Insert(new { TRS_KEY = "3422", InsertedDateTime = DateTime.Now });
        //var queryResult = db.Query(r.TableRef).Insert(columns, values);

        db.Logger = compiled => {
                                    context.Logger.Log($"{compiled.ToString()}");
                                };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        context.Logger.LogLine($"{ex.ToString()}");
    }
}
```

When I pass these objects to SqlKata in order to do the `INSERT` however, and log the compiled query to a log, as you can see, the values are all empty, so it's just ,,,,, almost the whole way, EXCEPT for two values I add manually just before running the query. Those appear OK.

```
INSERT INTO [TLog050000TicketEnd] ([TRS_KEY], [TRS_PTR], [TicTtl],
                                   [VoidTic], [SaveTrs], [RclTrs], [DrvOff], [QuickStore], [InfGTtl],
                                   [TndrXchng], [CpnTic], [TndrTic], [IHPay], [IHPurch], [SendEmail],
                                   [TicetID], [TaxVal], [Items], [Amount], [DiscAmt], [AmountNT],
                                   [DiscNT], [GTtlAmt], [RetnID], [FSPmt], [AmtEleCpn], [ZCnt],
                                   [TailFlags], [MmbrFirst], [STORE_ID], [last_modified]) 
VALUES (, , , ,
        , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 
        'A777', '2019-08-03 20:11:12')
```

Now the columns (`IEnumerable<string> columns`) come out fine, as you can see, and the two values I add manually also show up, but all the values placed into `IEnumerable<object>` values (and then copied to `valAdded`) don't show up at all?

I don't understand why.

I have even looped through the `IEnumerable` and can see every value in it when I output to the the log, e.g.

```
foreach (var v in valAdded)
{
    context.Logger.LogLine($"{JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v)}");
}
```

Output:

```
1720.0 11 false false false false false false true false false false false false false 577 0.0 0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

Can anyone help me work out where I've gone wrong here? :( I'm freaking out.

Comment: Exception handling is a pet peeve of mine and I see a serious issues here - you are catching Exception. That is a cardinal sin of exception handling. And after you do that once with a Fatal Exception, not even god can tell you way your programm does what. I do have two articles on this mater I link often: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: It's prototype code Chris, I'm trying to solve a problem, once that problem is solved, I can go back and handle individual exceptions as required. Your point is no less valid, but it has little to do with the issue I'm facing in this particular question. Whenever I'm trying to smash out a test of a concept, I wrap a general try,catch to log whatever might happen to a log. I clean that up later.

Comment: and despite it being prototype code to work this specific issue out, the try, catch included still meets some of the criteria mentioned in the link, e.g. Generic Exceptions caught should be published (tick), and Log Exception.ToString(); never log only Exception.Message! (tick).  But either way, it's an aside from the question itself.

Comment: You should use `db.Query().Insert()` instead of `db.Query().AsInsert()` then `query.Get()`;
`query.Get()` should be used only for select statements

Comment: I suggest to cast the values list to string, something like `values.Cast<string>()`